# Get size of UI before actually creating one?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am working on an Android app that is largely driven by code, not xml.

The Adapter for a ListView wants to know the height of the item.  But this in turn could depend on the size of UI elements within the item.  For example, if the item contains a checkbox, the size of the checkbox could influence the layout of the list item, which in turn could change the height, depending on whether or not a line wrap became necessary.

Question -- is there a way to get the size of an Android UI element without actually creating it?  Similar to the way one can use a Paint or TextPaint object to get the size of text before it is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating it? No, but you could use the `MeasureSpec` class and measure the View manually after you create it. Why do you need to know the exact size? Can't you just set the LayoutParams to `MATCH_PARENT` (width) and `WRAP_CONTENT` (height) for your case?

That said, if you do need to know, you could use the width of your `ListView` for the width MeasureSpec, and then UNSPECIFIED for the height MeasureSpec:

```
// Tell the View it should be exactly as wide as the ListView...
int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

// ... and as tall as it wants to be ...
int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

// ... measure it with these constraints ...
item.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

// ... and retrieve the measured height.
int itemHeight = item.getMeasuredHeight();
```